# Why isn't javascript applying a style on a element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This piece of code `masteries = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden-masteries");` return this on console:

```
[<div class=​"hidden-masteries">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"hidden-masteries">​…​</div>​]
```

And this is the complete code:

```
var masteries = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden-masteries");
for (var m = masteries.length-1; m >= 0; m--) {
    if (m == 0) {
    masteries.top = 0;
    } else {
    masteries.bottom = 0;
    }
}
```

It should add the css propertie `top: 0;` to element 0 and `bottom: 0;` to the other, but both is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `masteries[m].style.top = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

CSS properties are not being added in this way. You have to set `materies[m].style.top`

Answer (score 1):

You need to index into the node list, and then operate on the `style` object:

```
  masteries[m].style.top = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var masteries = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden-masteries");
for ( var m = masteries.length-1 ; m >= 0 ; --m ) {
    masteries[m].style[ m > 0 ? "bottom" : "top" ] = "0px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be `masteries.style.top = 0`?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_top.asp